# How to toggle a variable from true to false

Tags: jquery, button, toggle

I have this setup: http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/yJPGa/5/

I can't figure out how how to toggle in between a true or false variable. Here is the code:

```
<div class="test" id="id_test">Some Content...</div>
<div style="display: none" id="id_test">Some Other Content...</div>
<div>
  <button id="disable">Save</button>
  <button id="enable">Edit</button>
</div>
```

js

```
var logged_in = false;

$("#disable").click(function() {
  logged_in == true;
  alert (logged_in);
});

$("#enable").click(function() {
  logged_in == false;
  alert (logged_in);
});

if (logged_in == true) {
  $("#id_test").find(".test").removeClass(".test").addClass(".test_hidde");
}
```

css

```
.test{color: red;font-size: 16px;}
.test_hidde{color: #000;font-size: 26px;}
```

Comment: Right now, `logged_in` isn't changing at all. Inside the click functions, do you mean `logged_in = true;` and `logged_in = false;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here ya go in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/yJPGa/7/

changed the lines: `logged_in == true;` ==> `logged_in = true;`
and `logged_in == true;` ==> `logged_in = false;`

`==` denotes boolean check whereas `=` sets something as equal to something else

---

Here is a fiddle with the if statement fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/yJPGa/8/

The statement has to be encapsulated in a function

Comment: thanks for response, but the if statement doesn't work for some reason

Answer (score 33):

```
logged_in = !logged_in
```

Will do the trick.

Also, these two lines are the same:

```
if (logged_in == true)
if (logged_in)
```

Comment: this will return false sometimes on a reclick (and the same goes for true)

Comment: tested it and found no problems with using it. seems like it's the best solution, +1!
proof: http://jsfiddle.net/bAKa6/1/

Comment: great shorthand for javascript toggle/toggling a variable true/false.